# numpy ifft output has much larger power than original signal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I'm having a weird problem using the numpy fft class. I have the following bit of test code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

fs, a = scipy.io.wavfile.read('test.wav')   # import audio file

spectrum = np.fft.fft(a)                    # create spectrum

b = np.real(np.fft.ifft(spectrum))          # reconstruct signal

# Print power of original and output signal
print(np.average(a**2))
print(np.average(b**2))
```

It outputs:

```
1497.887578558565
4397203.934254291
```

As expected for these values, the output is much louder than the input. The documentation for numpy.fft.ifft states:

"This function computes the inverse of the one-dimensional n-point discrete Fourier transform computed by fft. In other words, ifft(fft(a)) == a to within numerical accuracy."

Thus the signal should be nearly identical. Yet they are obviously not.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to find the solution myself in the end.

The problem arises because the output of wavfile.read is an integer array. For some reason, the fft function handles integers in a different manner than floats. The problem is solved by typecasting a to an np.float64 type.

Why this happens is still not quite clear to me though.